# Does jQuery have a :target pseudo-class similar to CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

Does jQuery have a `:target` pseudo-class similar to CSS3?

If so, a demo would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can select psudo-classes.

Comment: I have difficulty seeing how the `:target` concept could work with jQuery.

Comment: @lonesomeday Me too! Just curious if there's a fallback for older browsers?

Answer (score 5):

Built-in, I don't think so, but you could jerry-rig one like so:

```
$(location.hash);
```

EDIT: Thanks, **Graham**!

ANOTHER EDIT:  Here's an example of a jQuery equivalent to `:target`. Since older browsers may not recognize the `window.onhashchange` event, and `location.hash` is generally updated at the end of the handler for an anchor tag's `onclick` event (rendering the new hash unavailable to the jQuery selector during the handler unless `location.hash = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf('#'));` is called beforehand), we have to use the clipped `href` value of the clicked anchor as the selector instead: http://jsfiddle.net/xPMzV/

Comment: This seams interesting. Could you provide a demo like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/c9BvU/

Comment: See below - you don't need the prefixed '#' as the hash property includes the literal hash symbol.

Comment: Ah that's right. I'm so used to stripping the `#` character from `location.hash` that sometimes I forget it exists. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

It will work in browsers that support both [`document.querySelectorAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304115%28VS.85%29.aspx) *and* the `:target` pseudo-class, and throw an error in browsers that do not (IE7 and IE8).  This is because jQuery uses the browser's native `document.querySelectorAll()` if available, and falls back to the [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) selector engine otherwise.  Annoyingly, [Sizzle does not support the `:target` selector](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Home):

> Sizzle supports virtually all [CSS 3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) – this even includes some parts that are infrequently implemented such as escaped selectors (“.foo\+bar”), Unicode selectors, and results returned in document order. There are a few notable exceptions to the CSS 3 selector support (the reasoning for this decision can be [found here](http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-that-people-actually-use/)):
>
> - :root
> - **:target**
> - :nth-last-child
> - :nth-of-type / :nth-last-of-type / :first-of-type / :last-of-type / :only-of-type
> - :lang()

Since sizzle does not support `:target`, jQuery will throw an error when it is used in older browsers.

Try this page in various browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/NPNFg/

The good news is it is trivial to add a `:target` selector yourself:

```
$.expr[":"].target = function (node) {
    var t = location.hash.substr(1);
    return t && node.id == t || node.name == t;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/NPNFg/3/

**Edit:**  You can get IE7 and IE8 to work with `:target` styles by duplicating your `:target` style definitions, replacing `:target` with `.target`.  Note, you would have to duplicate the entire definition, because if you try to use the `:target` pseudo-class in the rule definition's selector, IE8 chokes on it and doesn't parse the rule at all.  After duplicating your styles, use the [hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin, and use this code:

```
$(function () {
    try {
        $(":target");
    }
    catch (err) {
        $.expr[":"].target = function (node) {
            var t = location.hash.substr(1);
            return t && node.id == t || node.name == t;
        }
        $(window).hashchange(function () {
            $(".target").removeClass("target");
            $(":target").addClass("target");
        });
    }
});
```

Working demo adapted from [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/c9BvU/): http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/c9BvU/6/

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just do:

```
   $(window.location.hash)
```